# Hide different std::map compare parameters in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, polymorphism

I have a class that looks like this:

```
template<typename comparer>
class MyClass {
  std::map<std::uint32_t, MyElementType, comparer> entries;
public:
  void doSomething(std::uint32_t key, const MyElementType& el) {
    ...
  }
};
```

And I would like to use MyClass after it has been specialized with different comparers in a way that is agnostic to the specific comparer. What would be the most elegant way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::function` for the comparator.

```
using MyMap = std::map<std::uint32_t, int, std::function<bool(std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t)>>;
MyMap entries1{[](std::uint32_t a, std::uint32_t b){ return a < b; }};
MyMap entries2{[](std::uint32_t a, std::uint32_t b){ return a > b; }};
```